# What PIN encryption algorithm does the BA command at Thales payShield HSM use?

Tags: hardware-security-module

Unfortunately, there is no information about these algorithms in the Thales payShield HSM documentation. Only in the description of the "PIN encryption algorithm" setting it is said that two PIN encryption algorithms to be used: A (Visa method) or B (Racal method). Does anyone know what these algorithms are or where to find their descriptions?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=algorithms-visa-pin

Comment: Thank you, Elias! The link you provided contains information about PVV Generation Algorithm, PVV Verification Algorithm, Interbank PIN Generation Algorithm, and not about PIN encryption algorithms. Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: You failed to say what you are trying to achieve. BA command is extremely sensitive/dangerous and should be disabled in security configuration of your HSM as it enables PIN disclosure attacks on encrypted PIN Blocks. What you have in BA command results should be treated as opaque value encrypted under LMK and format is irrelevant as in normal operation you shouldn't even have access to LMK to decrypt it.

Summarizing, what are you trying to do so the format is relevant?

Comment: Michal, thank you so much for your comment! In fact, I have heard about PIN disclosure attacks, but have not seen published results on this topic. Maybe you know about these publications? I would be very grateful if you would send a link to these results. So, I decided to understand why these attacks are possible, but I did not find a description of the encryption algorithms used in the BA command anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also interested in this. I've searched the internet and internal Thales Docs.

In the payShield 9000 General information document (1270A593-030 General Information v3.0b.pdf) there is a following explanation:
Visa PIN Encryption Algorithm - Proprietary technique used by the HSM to encrypt PINs with the LMK for storage on a host database; sometimes referred to as Algorithm A.

So, unfortunately, this might not be an actual, standardized VISA algorithm, but HSM proprietary algorithm that Thales did not disclose.

The other one - Racal PIN Encryption Algorithm: Proprietary technique used by the HSM to encrypt PINs under the LMK for storage on a host database; an alternative to the Visa PIN Encryption Algorithm and sometimes referred to as Algorithm.

This one also seems to be a proprietary algorithm developed by Thales (formerly Racal) and the implementation is not publicly disclosed.

There might be a way to decrypt an LMK encrypted PIN, but it's a bit convoluted. In Test environment you could use a test AES Keyblock LMK; convert PIN to new PIN block format and then decrypt that following the standard implementation of ISO PIN block format 4.